# Bayesian estimation for the distribution of the results of an experiment when the cardinality of the result set is unknown

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, estimation, likelihood

Suppose I have an experiment ***X*** with mutually exclusive outcomes from a set *S*. My goal is to determine the probability distribution for *S*. The problem is that I do not know how many elements are in *S* to begin with. I have an idea of an upper limit of the size of *S* (let's say 10) but I do not know exactly.

**What is the Bayesian approach to determining the probability of each outcome? Is a Bayesian approach even appropriate here?**

If a concrete example is needed, consider a bag with an infinite number of differently-colored marbles. I know that there are at most 10 unique marble colors, but I do not know how many. My desire is a Bayesian approach to estimate the number of colors in the bag and to determine the likelihood of drawing a marble of a given color.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem with a hierarchical model where the number of colors in the bag is first drawn from a distribution over integers ranging from 1 to infinity (say, a Poisson distribution), then a subset of colors are drawn at random from the possible colors, and finally a probability vector over these colors is chosen at random.  For details, see the paper ["Efficient Bayesian Parameter Estimation in Large Discrete Domains"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.27.4689).